# Error when deploying SpringBoot application in local Tomcat server

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, kotlin, tomcat

I have the following application with SpringBoot 2.7

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication : SpringBootServletInitializer() {
    override fun configure(application: SpringApplicationBuilder):     SpringApplicationBuilder? {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication::class.java)
    }

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication::class.java, *args)
    }
}

/*@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}*/
```

The application.properties looks as follows:

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/planesserver
spring.datasource.username = username 
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

The gradle configuration is:

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.7.0"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.7.0"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.7.0"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.6.21"
    id("org.flywaydb.flyway") version "6.4.4"
}

group = "com.planes"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
     implementation("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper")
     implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
     implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
     implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
     implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
     implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
     implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
     implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
     implementation("io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.0")
     implementation("org.postgresql:postgresql")
     implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core")
     testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
         exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

springBoot {
    mainClass.set( "com.planes.planesserver.DemoApplication")
}
```

When I am running the application in the IntelliJ Idea it runs correctly - I am using the now commented code in the DemoApplication class.

I installed a tomcat server locally and I am deploying the application as a war - DemoApplication extends now SpringBottServletInitializer. Now I receive the following error in the catalina.log file:

org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

I looked up other cases like this in SO but they do not seem to apply to me.

Can anyone please give me a hint in the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to configure the datasource into a Bean as follows:

```
@Configuration
class JpaConfig {
    @Bean
    fun dataSource(): DataSource {
        val dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create()
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver")
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/server")
        dataSourceBuilder.username("username")
        dataSourceBuilder.password("password")
        return dataSourceBuilder.build()
    }
}
```

I am sure that this not the only possible solution, but this was the first that worked after a long time of searching for a solution.